# How to process data read from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am processing data read from database on the server using the following code:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text : {type : String, default: ''},
    created_at : Date
});

var processTodos = function ( todos ){

  for (var i = todos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Following update is not happening
    todos[i].created_at = "Custom date";
  };

  console.dir(todos);

  return todos;

};
```

I am not able to figure out how to update this. Is there a syntax issue that is causing this.

I am using MEAN stack for my application.

```
// Following update is not happening
todos[i].created_at = "Custom date";
```

What am i missing here.

Here is the console log for "console.dir(todos);":

```
{ _id: 5489dda3f23f159400475dba,
  created_at: Thu Dec 11 2014 23:38:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  __v: 0,
  text: 'Testing sorting at server side' }
{ _id: 5489ddacf23f159400475dbb,
  created_at: Thu Dec 11 2014 23:38:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  __v: 0,
  text: 'It works' }
{ _id: 5489f31a12fa54cc127f3e1d,
  created_at: Fri Dec 12 2014 01:10:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  __v: 0,
  text: 'time to add more data' }
```

Comment: What is a problem? You don't paste any code calling processTodos. Do you want update record in db?

Comment: You never save or update anything, you just set the local object's `created_at` value. There's no magical binding that makes model instances save themselves.

Comment: @farincz I have read data from db and want to change the 'created_at' date format before i send it to angular for onscreen display.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am doing the post processing on the data read from db. But i am not able to see the updation of 'todos[i].created_at'. Updating the console log.

Comment: Then problem is somewhere else (maybe you sending something different that you think) Code you posted looks ok. Paste your view handler.

Comment: You mean you're updating it after read and not expecting it to persist to the DB?

Comment: Yes, i am processing it before displaying it on screen.

Comment: I understand that; I was trying to confirm that you didn't care that you were actually trying to save the data. `"Custom date"` isn't a date, and IIRC Mongoose will validate the type. Have you tried passing it a valid date as a sanity check?

Comment: Date assignment works but i want to add a string to it. Will that not work?

Comment: @jsbisht A string isn't a date. You'd probably have to look at Mongoose's schema validation stuff. Personally I think that's the wrong approach; use a different field, or a different mechanism altogether, e.g., give the view a collection of objects, each with a `todo` and the custom not-date you want to display instead of the date. Basically a presenter patter, or you could decorate. Conflating two different data types is a smell.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Looks like i have a lot to pick up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to save the changes you're making to your object, you need to persist the change using the `.save()` method like so:

var processTodos = function ( todos ){
  for (var i = todos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Following update is not happening
    todos[i].created_at = "Custom date";
    todos[i].save();
  };
  console.dir(todos);
  return todos;
};